# Aimer, emploi intransitif

Tags: verbes, transitivité

A. dit à B. :

> Ils se sont aperçus de notre amitié. Et ils n’ont pas **aimé**. (*)

(*) Ils n'approuvent pas notre amitié.

La [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aimer) écrit que l'emploi absolu est possible et qu'il signifie *être amoureux*. Mais j'ai l'impression que ma deuxième phrase est aussi possible. Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Oui, il ne s'agit pas de l'emploi intransitif décrit dans le TLFi qui indique : *L'objet n'est pas suggéré par le contexte*.

Ici, l'objet du « non-amour » est ce dont ils se sont aperçus, c'est à dire l'amitié en question.

Comment: Mais le sens que je donne à la 2ème phrase est aussi possible, non ? Je ne suis pas sûre, car je n'ai trouvé une autre définition sur l'emploi absolu nulle part.

Comment: @Oreste Le sens de ta deuxième phrase est non seulement possible mais c'est le seul possible pour cette phrase. *Ils n'ont pas aimé* signifiant *ils n'ont pas été amoureux* est une hypothèse très improbable, quel que soit le contexte.